# Can we login directly to ecs containers using SSM Sessions Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am trying to understand if it is possible to directly login to ECS containers through SSM Sessions Manager, instead of login to the ec2 instance and then login to container.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. If you want to be able to ssh into your tasks on ECS, you can run [linuxserver/openssh-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/openssh-server) as a sidecar container. This will allow you to ssh into the task into that container, but not to the other contains, unless they support ssh.

If you are using [awsvpc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html) networking mode in you task you will be able to query your services, for example, using `curl` on the other containers in the task through `localhost`.